# rails c command fails: Your bundle is locked to CFPropertyList (2.3.4) How to resolve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I was developing an app of mine where when I try to run `rails c`, it leads to this error:

```
Your bundle is locked to CFPropertyList (2.3.4), but that version could not be 
found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, 
that means the author of CFPropertyList (2.3.4) 
has removed it. 
You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of CFPropertyList (2.3.4) 
that hasn't been removed in order to install.
```

Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I don't what caused this error all of a sudden but this only seems to appear when I run `rails c`. All other rails commands work properly. I've tried running `bundle install` and `bundle update` but the error persists. Has anyone encountered this error before? Would it be advisable to simply remove the offending line in `Gemfile.lock'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your `Gemfile.lock` and rerun `bundle install`. It will be rebuilt with the appropriate dependencies. If you're still having issues, you may have a version/dependency conflict between two or more gems.